# SQL: Filter dates by today date in where clause

Tags: sql

I have a stored procedure and would like to filter dates by today date(2020-06-25) in where clause.

Example :

| StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-06-23 | 2020-06-23 |
| 2020-06-23 | 2020-06-24 |
| 2020-06-23 | 2020-06-25 |
| 2020-06-25 | 2020-06-26 |
| 2020-06-25 | 2020-07-10 |
| 2020-06-26 | 2020-06-26 |

I have tried with `StartDate >= '2020-06-25' AND EndDate >='2020-06-25'`, but it is not working.

Please help me to get desired output would be

| StartDate | EndDate | Show |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-06-23 | 2020-06-23 | No |
| 2020-06-23 | 2020-06-24 | No |
| 2020-06-23 | 2020-06-25 | Yes |
| 2020-06-25 | 2020-06-26 | Yes |
| 2020-06-25 | 2020-07-10 | Yes |
| 2020-06-26 | 2020-06-26 | No |

Comment: why the last row is excluded?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and date/time functions are highly vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1):

It applies to events in the specific date (`'2020-06-25'`), but also to events which start before this date, and end after.

```
StartDate <= '2020-06-25' And EndDate >= '2020-06-25'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from tbl_name 
where getdate() Between StartDate And EndDate
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`BETWEEN`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp) operator.

In MySQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE CURDATE() BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate
```

In SQL Server:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE GETDATE() BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate
```